# How to use a foreach loop, but do something different on the last iteration?

Tags: php

This is probably a simple question, but how do you iterate through an array, doing something to each one, until the last one and do something different?

I have an array of names. I want to output the list of names separated by commas.

> Joe, Bob, Foobar

I don't want a comma at the end of the last name in the array, nor if there is only one value in the array (or none!).

**Update:** I can't use `implode()` because I have an array of User model objects where I get the name from each object.

```
$users = array();
$users[] = new User();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
    echo ', ';
}
```

How can I achieve this and still use these objects?

**Update:** I was worrying too much about how many lines of code I was putting in my view script, so I decided to create a view helper instead. Here's what I ended up with:

```
$array = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $array[] = $user->name;
}
$names = implode(', ', $array);
```

Comment: @Andrew, I updated my question with a answer to your update.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `implode`:

```
$names = array('Joe', 'Bob', 'Foobar');
echo implode(', ', $names); # prints: Joe, Bob, Foobar
```

To clarify, if there is only one object in the array, the `', '` separator will not be used at all, and a string containing the single item would be returned.

**EDIT:** If you have an array of objects, and you wanted to do it in a way other than a `for` loop with tests, you could do this:

```
function get_name($u){ return $u->name; };
echo implode(', ', array_map('get_name', $users) ); # prints: Joe, Bob, Foobar
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately I can't use implode() because the array contains objects. Is there a different way I can achieve the same thing?

Comment: In PHP 5.3+ you don't even have to declare a function, just do it anonymously: implode(', ', array_map(function($user) { return $user->name; }, $users)

Comment: Is it bad that I've been writing php for years and never thought of this?

Comment: @Brendan, no its not. Its just when you work with PHP after using Ruby, you think differently about `Arrays` :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$array = array('joe', 'bob', 'Foobar');
$comma_separated = join(",", $array);
```

output: 
`joe,bob,Foobar`

Comment: apparently join is an alias for implode :)

Comment: I actually prefer the use of join because it doesn't confuse those coming from a java/perl background.

Comment: I know! Sadly, `split` is not an alias for `explode`. So in PHP I just use `explode` and `implode` as lame as the names are :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately I can't use join() because the array contains objects. Is there a different way I can achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you might not want to use implode.
The trick then is to use an auxiliary variable to monitor not the last, but the first time through the loop.
vis:

```
$names = array('Joe', 'Bob', 'Foobar');
$first = true;
$result = '';
foreach ($names as $name)
{
   if (!$first)
      $result .= ', ';
   else
      $first = false;

   $result .= $name;
}
```

Comment: That is messing with my head.

Answer (score 1):

`implode(', ', $array_of_names)`

Answer (score 1):

psuedocode....

```
integer sigh=container.getsize();
sigh--;
integer gosh=0;
foreach element in container
{
  if(gosh!=sigh)
    dosomething();
  else 
    doLastElementStuff();
  gosh++;
}
```

looking at all the other answers, it seems PHP has gotten a lot more syntactic S since I last wrote anything in it :D

Comment: I'd give you a +1 for reading the title, but I would have to give a -1 for not reading the question :)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I must have stumbled across it right after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I come accross this a lot building SQL statements etc.

```
$joiner = " ";
foreach ($things as $thing) {
    echo "  $joiner $thing \n";
    $joiner = ',';
}
```

FOr some reason its easier to work out the logic if you think of the ",", "AND" or "OR" as an option/attribute that goes before an item. The problem then becomes how to suppress the the "," on the first line.

Comment: Very cool as long as white space isn't an issue. But the concept is strong, and you could write it differently to remove the extra whitespace. +1

Answer (score 0):

I personally found the fastest way (if you're into micro optimization) is:

```
  if(isset($names[1])) {
     foreach ($names as $name) {
       $result .= $name . ', ';
    }
    $result = substr($result, 0, -2);
  } else {
    $result = $names[0];
  }
```

`isset($names[1])` is the fastest (albeit not so clear) way of checking the length of an array (or string). In this case, checking for at least two elements is performed.

Comment: You need `-2` instead of `-1` to remove the space __and__ the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find it easier to create my comma delimited text a little differently.  It's a bit more wordy, but it's less function calls.

```
<?php

$nameText = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nameArray); $i++) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        $nameText = $nameArray[$i];
    } else {
        $nameText .= ',' . $nameArray[$i];
    }
}
```

It adds the comma as a prefix to every name except where it's the first element if the array.  I have grown fond of using **for** as opposed to **foreach** since I have easy access to the current index and therefore adjacent elements of an array.  You could use **foreach** like so:

```
<?php

$nameText = '';
$nameCounter = 0;
foreach ($nameArray as $thisName) {
    if ($nameCounter === 0) {
        $nameText = $thisName;
        $nameCounter++;
    } else {
        $nameText .= ',' . $thisName;
    }
}
```

Comment: But `count` evaluates again on each loop, so you still have one function call per loop. Additionally, you are introducing an `if` statement on every loop as well.